# Is there a way to differentiate between success and error API answers in Swift when there is no request status in response?

Tags: swift

I'm creating a login page, and I used to handle API error such as:

```
{"status":"error","answer":"Password is wrong"}
```

this way:

```
if error?["status"] as? String == "error" {
 Alert.showBasic(title: error!["status"] as! String, message: error!["answer"] as! String, vc: self)
```

This worked perfectly. But now I'm working with another API, that responds to my request this way:

```
{"password":["password is wrong"]}
```

The confusion what I have, is that I don't get from API answer, a status for my request, like success or error.

Is there a way to handle it?

Comment: What does the response look like when it succeeds?

Comment: Looks the same! here is an example of success: 
{"phone":"123456789","email":"someemail@ios.com","id":147}

Comment: I didnt know there can be api responses completely without status code :o

Comment: But does the response look the same when there is an error, I doubt that?

Comment: Error response is written in question.
{"password":["password is wrong"]}

Comment: I meant the ordinary response, anyway I assume error is nil if status is ok?

Comment: Error response:
{"password":["password is wrong"]}

Ok response:
{"phone":"123456789","email":"someemail@ios.com","id":147}

How Compiler will differentiate between both? I see them the same.

if error != nil won't do anything here. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The    `error != nil` depends and what you feed to your model and how you feed depends on status code

```
 if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
            switch httpResponse.statusCode {
               case 200 : //handle Root data model
               case 401 : //handle wrong password model
            }
        }
```

URLSession error is different . Its when the request is failed and no response . But you got the response but its up to you differentiate whether its good or bad.
Server response should be static if there is a change not noticed to you means something wrong in the backend.